# Unable to drop user in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I've created a user in PostgreSQL that I cannot drop, perhaps because the user has double quotes in the name itself.

Running \du in psql shows me:

```
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 “stack_advice” | Create DB                                                  | {}
```

`DROP USER 'stack_advice';`, `DROP USER "stack_advice";`, `DROP USER stack_advice;` 
all report this error: `ERROR:  role "stack_advice" does not exist`

How do I drop the user in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it has “smart quotes” on it, so you must include those:

```
DROP USER “stack_advice”;
```

Note that `'` and `"` are interpreted by Postgres but `“` and `”` are typographical constructs with no meaning, Postgres treats them like any other character like .

It's possible that this was put into a non-code text editor first which "fixed" the quotes, so try copy-pasting the literal text you see in the output to match it precisely.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for including the smart quotes in your answer. For reference, on Windows, you can type smart quotes by 1) Turning on Num Lock 2) Hold down Alt and type 0147 on the numeric keypad for left quotes and Hold down Alt and type 0148 on the numeric keypad for right quotes.

Comment: Don't forget: You included them in your question.